# ReferenceError: "validate" is not defined. while trying to submit a form with HTMLUnit

Tags: javascript, java, web-crawler, htmlunit, referenceerror

I want to submit a form to [this](http://tagmp3.net/) site with HTMLUnit but I get the error in title.

**Here is my code:**

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME, "127.0.0.1", 57703)) {
    //webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://tagmp3.net/");
    final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page1.getElementById("urlForm");
    final DomNodeList<DomElement> forms = page1.getElementsByTagName("form");
    final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) forms.get(0);
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("filepath");
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("button");
    textField.setValueAttribute(url);
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    System.out.println(page2.getBaseURL());
}
```

**And here is the Error I get:**

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[4] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot set property "innerHTML" of undefined to "<form></form><form></form>" (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js#4)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property "innerHTML" of undefined to "<form></form><form></form>" (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js#4)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)      
    blah blah blah....
```

I tried to turn off script error but it didn't work.

By the way I found this in the HTML of the website:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)" method="post" action="index.php">
```

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: Can you post a slightly larger section of code? Are you sure the exception is related to the code you posted here?

Comment: I'm sure. the rest of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: Where are textField and url defined?

Comment: text field is in the 7th line of the code I provided and this is almost the definition of url(I can't provide the exact url bc there are some sensitive info in it but its smth like this and when I put it in my browser it attempts to download the file and the file is correct:"https://api.telegram.org/file/aaaa/music/LARGHETTO.mp3" this is actualy one of the files that gets the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line on top:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Edge support is still incomplete, can you please try with the Firefox 52 or Chrome simulation. Also please use the latest Snapshot build.